# Need something Swipe Left from Main Activity to go into another Activity

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I am making an Android Launcher, which simply has the App Names (Icons are hidden as I just want it to be very minimalist.

In the main activity, I have a list of all apps installed in a GridView.
(I want to change that to show only the selected Favourite apps)

I also have another activity where all apps are shown with Search functionality.

I want to be able to switch from Main Activity to the Full App page, as well as switch back to Main activity with swipes.

So Left swipe should bring app page which has (GridView of apps)
swipe right from that page brings me back (hopefully restore the previous activity)

I have tried a few different solutions, none of them is ideal as most do not work, and one only works when Swiping right from the top.

[Swipe left-right changes activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43584529/swipe-left-right-changes-activity)

I have tried the first solution provided in the above link

[image: Main Activity Page where I want to swipe left]
[image: App Activity Page where I want to swipe right]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/MainActivity"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:orientation="vertical">


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/top_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextClock
        android:id="@+id/clock"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="40sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dateView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp" />


</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/MainActivityApp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="6">
    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/appGrids"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:numColumns="1"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth">

    </GridView>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="2">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/setting"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_manage"
        />


</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi have a look and try this for gesture to left right bottom and call your next activity intent in on left section
  [Android: How to handle right to left swipe gestures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139288/android-how-to-handle-right-to-left-swipe-gestures)